# about JAVA com.alibaba.fastjson.JSONObject class extends, How to correct mistake?

Tags: java, class, extends

I want to extends com.alibaba.fastjson.JSONObject for new a function,follow is my code,but is wrong. how to correct mistake?

```
import com.alibaba.fastjson.JSONObject;
public class SJSONObject extends JSONObject 
  {
public String optString(String key) {
    if (containsKey(key)){
        return getString(key);
    }
    return "";
}
}
```

and then i use it:

```
SJSONObject jsobj  =(SJSONObject) JSON.parseObject(sb.toString());
String aa= jsobj.optString("ssss");
```

it is wrong!

Comment: Does `JSON.parseObject` (I'm assuming that's part of the alibaba API) have any knowledge of your custom class? How could it possibly return an instance of your custom class?

Comment: https://github.com/alibaba/fastjson/blob/master/src/main/java/com/alibaba/fastjson/JSONObject.java    this is orignal code @SotiriosDelimanolis

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis  wrong info : 严重: Servlet.service() for servlet CheckLogin threw exception java.lang.ClassCastException: com.alibaba.fastjson.JSONObject cannot be cast to com.testservlet.SJSONObject

Comment: Exactly, how is a library that knows nothing about your class return an instance of it?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis  how can i correct ??  I am beginner ,thank u

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to extend from JSONObject. Do something like this.

```
public class yourClass {

    public static String optString(JSONObject json, String key) {
        if (json.containsKey(key)){
            return json.getString(key);
        }
        else{
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

and your client code can be:

```
JSONObject json  = new JSON.parseObject(sb.toString());
String aa= youClass.optString(json, "ssss");
```